# Calculate the junction temperature of a MOSFET during pulse

Tags: mosfet, temperature, constant-current

Hi all I have a question regarding using a MOSFET for a constant current source. I have found this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/335507/calculate-junction-temperature-of-mosfet-during-pulse) with some answers but it wasn't clear to me yet.

I want to create a constant current LED driver with a MOSFET shunt and opamp configuration. I have designed the schematic below with a 1 ohm sense resistor and a BUK6D43-60E MOSFET. The forward voltage of the LED's will be between 34.5 and 45 volt and the current will be 1 ampere. So the voltage over the MOSFET will be around 12.5 volt maximum.
The LED's will be pulsed with a frequency of <100 Hz and a pulse duration with a maximum of 300 microseconds, this will be a dutycycle of 3%. From the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2632129.pdf?_ga=2.154839928.1167602042.1551944296-881260536.1549963479&_gac=1.144368001.1550828996.EAIaIQobChMIi4i2jojP4AIVyed3Ch3YpA8dEAAYASAAEgJyuvD_BwE) below I got a Zja of around 4-6 K/W. I know Tjunction = Tambient + Rj-a * P, now Tambient has a maximum of 60C and Rj-a = Zja = 4-6 K/W. Now what do I have to use for P? Is this (Vcc-Vleds-Vshunt) * If or is this (Vcc-Vleds-Vshunt) * If * dutycycle? Because this would be the difference between 135C and 62.25C.

[image: Datasheet]
[image: schematic]

Comment: P will be the power dissipated in the FET: the drain current TIMES the voltage across the source-to-drain.

Comment: Your MOSFET "only" dissipates power during the 300us pulse. As the DuCy is always less than 3% the average power will be only 3% of the dissipated power during the pulse. The power dissipation in the MOSFET is Vds * Id = 12.5 V * 1 A = 12.5 W. Make sure the MOSFET can handle that (it has a higher maximum power dissipation). Since the pulse is short, the heat can average out so 3% * 12.5 W = 0.375 W.

Comment: I think you're a decade mistaken regarding the Zja. 300 usec = 3 10^(-**4**), so, Zja is about 1.3 K/W

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for your input. I didn't know if the dutycycle was already in the Zj-a.

Comment: @Huisman I also realized this but since there is no graph in my region i decided to take the closest one possible.

Comment: There is... the previous graph Fig. 4. :-)

Comment: @Huisman That is the "Transient thermal impedance from junction to solder point" not to ambient.

Comment: You're right, I missed it.

Comment: *I didn't know if the dutycycle was already in the Zj-a* It does not exactly work like that. The DuCy limits the dissipated **Power** and less power means less temperature increase so less cooling is needed. You can do that here as the pulses are short. If the pulses were for example 1 second long then during the pulse the MOSFET might heat up too much. In your case you benefit from the **heat capacity** as that averages out the heat that needs to be dissipated.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Is there some sort of formula to calculate the dissipated power or temperature rise? Because I realize the Zj-a will change based on the temperature. And I would like to know if I have to add a heat sink or that it is okay just as is.

Comment: From the plot you can extrapolate that at a 300 us pulse (the plot shows only 1ms and up) and a 5% duty cycle (or less) you can expect a Zth of less than 5 K/W. At your 12.5 W dissipation during the pulse that means a junction temp. increase of 5 K/W * 12.5 W = 62.5 K. At 30 degrees ambient temperature that means 92.5 degrees C. That 92.5 C will be the junction temperature at the end of the 300 us pulse. That should be OK, most MOSFETs can handle (are designed for) a Tj of up to 125 or even 150 degrees C.

Comment: I think you need to understand the theory behind power dissipation, thermal resistance and temperatures a bit better. **It is not that complex!** Go read: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/heat-sink-calculator/ or https://www.designworldonline.com/how-to-select-a-suitable-heat-sink/ Once you get how that works, everything will become much more clear to you.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for the sources. Even though I know how thermal isolation works I don't really understand how a MOSFET works during current sinking and how that relates to its generation of heat. Also I don't know how I can calculate when it is needed to add a heat sink or I can just leave it on the PCB and let it cool by the ambient. The MOSFET I choose has a maximum Tj of 175C so that is even higher then the normal ones. So the basic question was more when I can assure the ambient temperature inside the casing is below 60C how do I calculate the cooling of the chip during off time.

Comment: *I don't really understand how a MOSFET works during current sinking* Simple: think of the MOSFET as a **variable resistor** where this resistor has a value that will result in a 1 A current. You mentioned there's 12.5 V across the MOSFET while 1 A flows. So the MOSFET acts as a 12.5 V / 1A = 12.5 ohm resistor which dissipates P = V * I = 12.5 V * 1 A  = 12.5 W.

Comment: You cannot easily calculate the cooling off time, you would need to know heat capacitance etc, make a model, that's really for experts only. Usually engineers just **overdesign** in such cases, so take large margins. From my calculations: you already have that. If you want to "play safe" even more, use a physically larger MOSFET. Your BUK6D43 is quite small, larger MOSFETs take longer to heat up (more heat capacitance) so can handle more than a small MOSFET.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yea that's why I choose this MOSFET because even with an ambient temperature of 60 degree C I have about 50 degrees C headroom. The only thing I don't know is how it will be over time. Does the MOSFET have enough time to cool down back to the ambient or is it a slow rise until it dies? The problem is more that I don't really have the room for a heat sink and would rather go to a larger MOSFET since this is cheaper in production.